# Complete (possibly official) list of "What is..." articles from the Notices of the AMS

Tags: reference-request

Does it exist online and where can one find it? (For example, these [two](http://arminstraub.com/math/what-is-column) [sources](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~whieldon/What_is....html) are not official; is the longer one complete?)

Comment: As far as I know, this column has only been around for about 10 years and appears in every issue. So exhaustive search should be feasible if you really need a complete list.

Comment: Actually, I asked this to avoid visiting every internet page of every month of the Notices... I'd like to have a set of links/addresses on one single page. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems they made a list in the meantime:

http://www.ams.org/publications/notices/whatis/noticesarchive

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work anymore : (

Comment: Maybe there is also this link : http://arminstraub.com/math/what-is-column

Comment: See also the [more recent answer below](https://mathoverflow.net/a/357493).

Answer (score 20):

I wrote to Allyn Jackson, who is in charge of this feature.  I reproduce her response below with her permission.

> I can indeed answer this, and unfortunately the answer is no.
>   Embarassingly, we don't
>   have an online index for the WHAT IS column.  The Notices web site is rather
>   primitive,
>   and there is no natural place to put such a list.  We are hoping to do an
>   upgrade soon,
>   and this would include a WHAT IS index.
>
> I knew about the list of WHAT IS columns at Cornell, but I didn't know about
>   the other
>   one at arminstraub.com.  I have my own list that I use in editing the
>   column, and, like
>   arminstraub, I have column #106 as Heil's "What is a frame?"  So it seems to
>   me that
>   the arminstraub list is complete, but I did not check every title against my
>   own list.  The
>   last column in my list is #110, so arminstraub is missing the 4 latest
>   columns.
>
> It is gratifying to know that there are some serious WHAT IS fans out there.
>   Comments
>   and suggestions are welcome and can be sent to notices-whatis@ams.org.

Answer (score 17):

Assuming you have access to MathSciNet, a [search](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?pg4=AUCN&s4=&co4=AND&pg5=TI&s5=what%20is&co5=AND&pg6=PC&s6=&co6=AND&pg7=JOUR&s7=notices&co7=AND&Submit=Search&dr=all&yrop=eq&arg3=&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&pg8=ET&s8=All&review_format=html) for Title containing "What is" and Journal containing "Notices" seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Unfortunately, not all of us have MathSciNet access, it is paid and expensive...

Answer (score 5):

It seems that this is an official (and complete) list
https://www.ams.org/cgi-bin/notices/amsnotices.pl?article_id=whatis&article_type=gallery&gallery_type=whatis